# Hapi Bell Twitter Auth with email

Tags: twitter, hapi.js, joi

I'm struggling to get the email address of twitter users when they login

I get the following error from Joi "Error: Uncaught error: Invalid options value: must be true, falsy or an object"

```
server.auth.strategy('twitter', 'bell', {
    provider: 'twitter',
    scope: ['public_profile', 'email'],
    config: {
        extendedProfile: true,
        getParams: 'include_email',
        getMethod: 'account/verify'
    },
    password: config.longpass, //Use something more secure in production
    clientId: config.twitter_key,
    clientSecret: config.twitter_secret,
    isSecure: config.useHttps //Should be set to true (which is the default) in production
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.

```
server.auth.strategy('twitter', 'bell', {
    provider: 'twitter',
    config: {
        getMethod: 'account/verify_credentials',
        getParams: {include_email:'true' },//doesn't work without quotes!
    },
    password: 'secret_cookie_encryption_password', //Use something more secure in production
    clientId: secret.twitterId,
    clientSecret: secret.twitterSecret,
    isSecure: false //Should be set to true (which is the default) in production
});
```

Don't forget to allow necessary permission (Request email addresses from users) in your Twitter application settings.